# Publish python dev version of package

Tags: python, pip, package

I need to publish a development version of python package without affect current cases where latest version is used. 
after testing(for some reason can't test locally), will need to publish the development version as latest version.

for example: current latest version is : 1.0

how should the dev version of package can be named.  1.0.dev or 1.1.dev or something else.

(pip install)

I want my dev version can only be install by "pip install packagename==version", not "pip install packagename"

Comment: pip install seems only check version of integer, so any string are fine for this situation

Answer (score 0):

any version with string is okay, for my case, 1.0 is the latest version, I use 1.1.dev for the development version. 
pip install packagename will only instal version 1.0